# Can Firefox OS apps read out USB pins?

Tags: usb, arduino, firefox-os, hardware-interface

I'm wondering if Firefox OS handsets could be useful as a platform for DIY hardware projects. Hence my question: Can Firefox OS apps read out USB pins?

Compared with Arduino it would be obviously be overpowered, but the handsets have decent battery life and all connection stuff like wifi already built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not right now, but we are working on USB support as part of the WebAPI work. The bug to monitor is here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737153

Comment: There is also ongoing work for building [serial API](https://github.com/whatwg/serial).